# Необходимо округлить цену в Woocommerce до кратной 5 в большую сторону: (1512 =>1515 или 1234 =>1235) при помощи sql запроса

Tags: sql, woocommerce, округление

Я смог уменьшить все цены при помощи этого запроса:
update wp_postmeta set meta_value = meta_value * 1.135 where meta_key='_price'
...
Работает отлично. Теперь некрасивые цены, нужно округлить до кратных пяти, чтобы цен вроде 12123 рубля не было.
Каким образом можно модифицировать мой запрос, написаный выше?

Comment: должно быть что-то вроде `meta_value = meta_value + (meta_value % 5)`. В общем, к числу остаток от деления на 5 прибавить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```sql
UPDATE wp_postmeta
   SET meta_value = meta_value - (meta_value % 5) + 5
 WHERE meta_value % 5 <> 0
   AND meta_key = '_price' 
;
```

Comment: Логику понял, выглядит просто. Только я не знаю синтаксис sql, подскажите, в таком варианте правильно?

UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = meta_value - (meta_value % 5) + 5
WHERE price % 5 <> 0 and meta_key='_price'
...
Нужно что-то вроде логического оператора "и" в условии, чтобы только поле с "_price" попадало?

Comment: Да, выглядит верно.  Можете для начала проверить на свей тестовой базе.

Comment: ответ попал в очередь проверки сообщений низкого качества. к чему бы? может быть он действительно не очень высокого качества?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin  Честно говоря, не вижу причин.  Если вы видите, расскажите.

Comment: как по-вашему, почему [эти ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa) получили так много голосов «за»? что их принципиально отличает от вашего ответа?

Comment: К сожалению этот вариант не работает. Возможно что-то в синтаксисе.
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = meta_value - (meta_value % 5) + 5 WHERE price % 5 <> 0 and meta_key='_price'

Comment: Попробовал следующий вариант:
update wp_postmeta 
set meta_value = meta_value - (meta_value % 5) + 5 
WHERE meta_key='_price' % 5 <> 0
Цены успешно изменились тка, как я и хотел. И Несколько других полей тоже. Восстановил их бекапа. Где косяк? Получается под WHERE price % 5 <> 0 and meta_key='_price'  попадает не тоолько прайс. Хм.

Comment: @Dmitriy_1988  Обновил ответ.  Посмотрите.

Comment: Нашел, в условии нужны скобки, вопрос закрыт, спасибо за поддержку! Верный вариант: update wp_postmeta set meta_value = meta_value - (meta_value % 5) + 5 WHERE (meta_key='_price') OR (meta_key% 5 <> 0);

Comment: Только заметил что Вы изменили ответ, значит проблема была во втором условии, я писал его сначала не верно.

Comment: Вы уверены, что там `OR`, а не `AND`?

Comment: Действительно! Значит несколько полей могут быть не корректными. Снова бекап восстановлю и сделаю с AND. Спасибо за замечание, товаров много, где не сработало, не заметил бы.

Comment: Проверяю, из-за OR поля, которые уже были кратные 5 стали на 5 больше, одно из условий не стабатывает, потому что есть второе, которое подходит. Вот и наглядная ошибка.

Comment: Проверьте, пожалуйста, внимательно мой вариант.  На моих тестовых данных он отрабатывает.  Если какие-то данные обновлены неверно или есть какая-то синтаксическая ошибка, напишите сюда.  Если всё отрабатывает как должно, вы можете отметить ответ как верный, нажав галочку.

Comment: Сбросил и использовал Ваш запрос, все сработало как нужно.